# WithEvents+Handles+Overrides

Tags: vb.net

Say I have an member (e.g., Button1) of an object (e.g., Form1) that is delared using withevents (e.g., Form1.Button1_Click), and there is a handler with 'Handles' in that object.

If I override it (say, Form2.Button1_Click), will the handler call the overriden version (like me.Button1_Click) or the one with the actual handles on it (like MyClass.Button1_Click)?

Here's what I tried:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Overridable Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MsgBox("Form1's Button")
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim f2 As New Form2
        f2.Show()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
    Inherits Form1

    Public Overrides Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        MsgBox("Form2's Button")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the `Overridable` modifier indicates that the method can be overridden.

To override is to *`reject or cancel (a decision, view, etc.)`.*

`Overrides` specifies that the method will override the existing event handlers implementation. The existing method in `Form1` will never be called unless you manually call it. You can manually call it by using `MyBase` keyword which essentially allows you to reference the base class of the current instance.

```
Public Overrides Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("SecondForm's Button")
    MyBase.Button1_Click(sender, e)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The overridden version is called. When I click button1 on Form1, I get 'Form1's Button'. When I start the second form using button2, I click button1, and get 'form2's button'

Just so anybody tries to google this and finds nothing like I did, I killed 10 minutes of my life to test it, and now nobody else will need to!